# ChartJS remove the legends at the top of the chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am generating charts with ChartJS v3.3.2. I don't want to show the legends. So I've set `legend: { display: false }` but the legends are still showing.

How can I fix this ?

here's my options object:

```js
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data,
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    responsive: true,
  },
};
```

[image: 1]

Comment: What version of chartjs do you use? If 3.x then check the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html) again and compare the mentioned namespace and your object.

Comment: What do you think this piece of code is doing: `legend: { display: true }` ?

Comment: @trash_dev I was doing testing with the code and haven't noticed that it was set to true, setting to true or false makes no difference.

Comment: @Andreas  I am using version 3.3.2 .

Answer (score 0):

As descripbed in the migration docs and the namespace in the legend config page in the docs it states that to configure the legend you need to put it in the plugins part of the config since its an internal plugin.

Migration docs: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html#specific-changes

Legend docs: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/configuration/legend.html#configuration-options

Working Example:

```js
let config01 = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: [
      'Part 01',
      'Part 02',
      'Part 03'
    ],
    datasets: [{
      data: [2000, 1000, 600],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgb(0, 76, 138)',
        'rgb(50, 151, 230)',
        'rgb(250, 202, 55)',
      ],
      hoverOffset: 10
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
    },
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart-01').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, config01);
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart-01" width="200px" height="200px"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.3.2/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
</div>
```